# How do I get my javascript var to return in an html paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple function just for fun for a friend, but my js function wont return x the way I want it.
I have a text field and a button. If a user inputs "no good lyer" x should return "Big Fucking Surprise!"
If a user inputs anything else with text, x should return "Leave her ass anyway!"
If a user doesn't input anything x should return "Make a decision!"

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to make a decision about your ex.</p>

<p id="choice">Here is your Decision</p>

<form>
My Ex:<input type="text" name="myEx">
</form>

<button onclick="myLife()">Decide</button>

<script>
   function myLife()
{
var x="";

if("myEx".text=="no good lyer")
{
x="Big Fu**ing Surprise!";
}

if("myEx".text!="no good lyer")
{
x="Leave her a** anyway!";
}

if("myEx".text=="")
{
x="Make a decision!"
}

document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=x
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are doing this script for a friend to show off your skills, it's not working(;

Comment: ...If I was, I wouldn't be here...I need answers not nonconstructive criticism. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should `use === and !== operator` to check for conditions,  Try the code below

```
To get a value from a input text use .value 




 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to make a decision about your ex.</p>

<p id="choice">Here is your Decision</p>

<form>
My Ex:<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
</form>

<button onclick="myLife()">Decide</button>

<script>
   function myLife()
{

  var myText = document.getElementById("myText");
var x="";

if(myText.value==="no good lyer")
{
x="Big surprise!";
}

if(myText.value!=="no good lyer")
{
x="Leave her!";
}

if(myText.value === "")
{
x="Make a decision!"
}
document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=x
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a billion. I'm still fairly new to this whole gig so I appreciate you re-writing it. It works just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but javascript strings don't have methods called `text`. your trying to get the value of the input `<input type="text" name="myEx">` with `'myEx'.text`, which is strange to say the least but you need to use normal people javascript. try `getElementsByName('myEx')[0]`

Add this variable to the top of your function `myLife`:

```
var myEx = document.getElementsByName('myEx')[0].value
```

change every line like this:

```
"myEx".text
```

to simply this

```
myEx
```

Answer (score 0):

change your script to following

```
<script>
function myLife()
{
    var x="";

    if("myEx".text=="no good lyer")
    {
        x="Big Fu**ing Surprise!";
    }

    if("myEx".text!="no good lyer")
    {
        x="Leave her a** anyway!";
    }

    if("myEx".text==null)
    {
        x="Make a decision!"
    }

    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=x
}
</script>
```